# Python3 SPEECH to TEXT

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am a 12 year old kid and am a beginner at programming. It would be great if someone could help be. below I have the code for my speech recognition application, I am on MAC OS CATALINA and the same error keeps on coming up, It prints out "say something", and then once I say something nothing happens and it stays frozen, once I stop the code running I get this error.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("SAY SOMETHING")
    audio = r.listen(source)
    print("THANK YOU")

try:
    print("TEXT:  "+r.recognize_google(audio))
except:
    print("SORRY I DONT KNOW WHAT YOU MEAN")
```

This is the error I get when I stop the code, once it is paused at SAY SOMETHING for a long time.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anishnagariya/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/Tester.py", line 8, in <module>
    print("THANK YOU")
  File "/Users/anishnagariya/PycharmProjects/AI/HelloWorld/lib/python3.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 620, in listen
    buffer = source.stream.read(source.CHUNK)
  File "/Users/anishnagariya/PycharmProjects/AI/HelloWorld/lib/python3.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 161, in read
    return self.pyaudio_stream.read(size, exception_on_overflow=False)
  File "/Users/anishnagariya/PycharmProjects/AI/HelloWorld/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 608, in read
    return pa.read_stream(self._stream, num_frames, exception_on_overflow)
KeyboardInterrupt

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: The minimum age to use Stack Overflow is 13 years old.  https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#age

Comment: In addition to that, the person in your profile picture does not at all look 12 years old.

Answer (score -1):

I would advise going through the documentation for the speech recognition module you're using:

https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst

Check this part specifically:

https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst#recognizer_instanceenergy_threshold--300---type-float

The energy threshold is described as such:

> Represents the energy level threshold for sounds. Values below this threshold are considered silence, and values above this threshold are considered speech. Can be changed.

You can set the threshold like this:

`r.energy_threshold = 4000`

Or you can do this which will adjust the threshold dynamically based on sound currently from the environment.

`r.dynamic_energy_threshold = True`

Also ensure your microphone is working properly

Edit:

https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst#recognizer_instancelistensource-audiosource-timeout-unionfloat-none--none-phrase_time_limit-unionfloat-none--none-snowboy_configuration-uniontuplestr-iterablestr-none--none---audiodata

Set a timeout &/or pause duration for the listen call.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

while True:
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("SAY SOMETHING")
        try:
            audio = r.listen(source, timeout=3)
            print("THANK YOU")
            break
        except sr.WaitTimeoutError:
            print("timed out")
try:
    print("TEXT:  "+r.recognize_google(audio))
except:
    print("SORRY I DONT KNOW WHAT YOU MEAN")
```

Comment: Hello, I tried that but it still doesn't work, I'm getting the same error. My mic is still working, I tested it out online and it shows its working.

Comment: Check my edit, a timeout might help to prevent endless listening.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but every time I try to say something it always goes to timeout, even if I say one word, there is no background noise either. The timeout is set to 10.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your microphone quality you will probably need to set some thresholds:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
r.energy_threshold = 1000
r.pause_threshold = 0.5

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("SAY SOMETHING")
    audio = r.listen(source)
    print("THANK YOU")

    try:
        print("TEXT:  " + r.recognize_google(audio))

    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("SORRY I DONT KNOW WHAT YOU MEAN")
```

It is also not good practice to have a bare except clause `sr.UnknownValueError` is the standard error for unknown speech in the `speech_recognition` library